Vite dev server loses connection in Chrome on inactive tab
I'm using sveltekit with vite dev server.
All seems usual, but after some chrome update (probably) it started to reload the tab when it's inactive for some time.
In console it shows [vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...
No errors nor connections errors.
In network tab connection has no errors. Just finished. Nothing is unusual.
The reload happens only when the tab is inactive and after some (random) time of 5+ seconds.
I have tried to disable Chrome memory saver (and had added my dev domain to exclusions). Nothing changed.
Any ideas about how to fix this? I'm going mad, frankly, it's so annoying.
